# Ubuntu 12.04 server Installation issue

Tags: 12.04

I have tried to install ubuntu 12.04 (32 & 64 bit) version on Fujitsu Primergy RX200S8 server. But at the time of base system installation the server get restarted itself without showing any error. I couldn't install ubuntu, why fujitsu server not supported ubuntu. Suggest me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you try the new 14.04 version?

Comment: I have tried ubuntu 12.04, 12.10, 13.10 and 14.04, nothing to be installed

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

- BIOS version 1.6.0 or 1.7.0
- RAID Ctrl SAS 6G (D3116C) or (D2616) or (D2607)

then let's try "ghes.disable=1" parameter as install option.

You press F6 and Ecs at the installation booting menu, then you can put the parameter.

This information comes from Fujitsu official page (in Japanese)
http://jp.fujitsu.com/platform/server/primergy/software/linux/products/distribution/pdf/rx200s8-non-support-os.pdf